# I'm trying to set the base price of an item to $3 but it's messing with the rest of my math (java)

Tags: java, math, methods, currency

So right now everything works fine so long as the volume of the item(p1v and p2v) is greater than 1 but I can't figure out a way for the console to print the base price of $3 if the volume is less than 1.  For reference the cost of an item starts at $3 for the first unit of volume or part thereof then increases by $1 for each additional unit.

```
public void calculateCost() {

        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        if (p1v < 1) {
            double cost = 3;
            System.out.printf("%nPackage 1 will cost " + currency.format(cost) + " to ship.");
        }

        if (p2v < 1) {
            double cost2 = 3;
            System.out.printf("%nPackage 1 will cost " + currency.format(cost2) + " to ship.");
        }

        if (p1v < 1 && p2v < 1) {

        double cost = 3 + p1v - 1;
        String message = "Package 1 will cost " + currency.format(cost) + " to ship.";
        System.out.printf("%n" + message);

        double cost2 = 3 + p2v - 1;
        String message2 = "Package 2 will cost " + currency.format(cost2) + " to ship.";
        System.out.printf("%n" + message2);

        if (cost >= 5 * cost2) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe first package is " + cost / cost2 + "times the cost of the second package.");
        } else if (cost2 >= 5 * cost) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe second package is " + cost2 / cost + "times the cost of the first package.");
        } else if (cost == cost2) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe first package is the same cost as the second package.");
        } else if (cost < 5 * cost2 && cost >= 4 * cost2) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe first package is quadruple the cost of the second package.");
        } else if (cost2 < 5 * cost && cost2 >= 4 * cost) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe second package is quadruple more than the cost of the first package.");
        } else if (cost < 4 * cost2 && cost >= 3 * cost2) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe first package is triple the cost of the first package.");
        } else if (cost2 < 4 * cost && cost2 >= 3 * cost) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe second package is triple the cost of the second package.");
        } else if (cost < 3 * cost2 && cost >= 2 * cost2) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe first package is twice the cost of the first package.");
        } else if (cost2 < 3 * cost && cost2 >= 2 * cost) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe second package is twice the cost of the second package.");
        } else if (cost < 2 * cost2) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe second package is slightly more than the cost of the first package.");
        } else if (cost2 < 2 * cost) {
            System.out.printf("%nThe first package is slightly more than the cost of the second package.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement? `if (volume < 1) { // base = 3 }`

Comment: I think sleepToken is right. Your basic issue is that the cost does not increase for each full unit right now, it will also increase for a partial unit (.25). So something like if (volume < 1) { cost = 3 } should work

Comment: So i added this: 
 
`if (p1v < 1) {double cost = 3;
            System.out.printf("%nPackage 1 will cost " + currency.format(cost) + " to ship.");
        }`
and another the same for (p2v) but if p1v is less than 1 it immediately exits the code, which is understandable.  is there a way to have it continue to the next if statement?

Comment: I'll edit the code above to reflect my changes